# Can a MitM attack occur on an ISP's local exchange or street wiring cabinet?

Tags: network, attacks

If an attacker were to dig up the 'outgoing feed' from my local exchange or the street cabinet, could they sniff my entire neighborhood's network traffic? Or is this infrastructure secured against this sort of attack?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Absolutely.

In practice, though, this is a complex and very risky attack - probably going to be easier to do something else.

Comment: doesn't stop the military doing it, I would point out it's harder with fiber optics as the interruption is usually instantly detected.

Comment: I'd say it does. The complexity stops the domestic military doing it (they can just walk into the ISP and ask for everything, much easier) and the risk stops foreign military doing it (people in Slough would notice a Russian tank parked next to a BT cabinet).

Comment: Ah, another Brit, and yeah, there is no point the local military flexing those muscles in the UK. Other countries have different regulations and different willing less to break those regulations, but how would we know if they did tap and MITM undersea cables with a submarine?

Comment: Tapping undersea cables would cause massive packet loss during the transition, immediately alerting the operators. Not to mention the fact that there are too many listening buoys on the sea bed for anyone to get close without being detected.

Comment: @ewanm89 You wouldn't care: that threat is mitigated by use of a separate secure channel.

Comment: Polynomial, really, I thought the point of a submarine is to be as stealthy as possible so the enemy doesn't know you are there. As for the packet loss, that would depend on how they did the tap, when they did the tap and what sort of cables it is, I already pointed out fibre optics are harder to tap, but there are still ways, if these are supposedly secure diplomatic cables I'm sure they are prime targets for enemy intelligence agencies.

Comment: @GrahamHill that's part of my point, you can trust any of the net anyway, so you should be using SSL.

Comment: @ewanm89 Sure, but there's not really any way to supress both noise and water pressure ripples coming from a sub in very deep water. The displacement caused by the sub moving will be caught by listening buoys and all sorts of deep-sea geology equipment we have down there. You'd need some sort of specialised ultra-slow-moving super-stealthy deep-sea fibre-hacking vehicle, which I doubt exist.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they could.

It wouldn't be terribly hard: those street cabinets aren't very physically secure.  At least, the ones in my neighborhood aren't.  On the other hand, there's some chance of detection (a neighbor might call the police if they see some suspicious character messing around with the cabinet late at night), and there are probably easier ways to make money.  Meanwhile, law enforcement and the military have other ways to tap your communications.  So this is probably a low risk.  There are probably other, better things to worry about.

But, if you are concerned about the risk, the defense is to use traffic encryption.  Use an encrypted VPN; use HTTPS Everywhere; use SSH; etc.